# Multithreading and Freeing Pointer Structs in c

Tags: c

In my program, I am working with multiple threads at once. In the event when I create my thread and send it to a function, I also want to send multiple arguments(parameters) along with it. After a little bit of research, I found the best way to do this is by sending the arguments in the form of a struct pointer. Essentially what I am working with is as follows:

```
//Following code runs within a loop
        Arguments *args = (Arguments*)malloc(sizeof(Arguments));
        args->start = start;
        args->end = end;
        args->target = target;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, splitSearch, (void*)args);
```

```
void * splitSearch(void *args){
    Arguments *arguments = (Arguments*)args;
    int *theStatus;
    int result = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=arguments->start; i < arguments->end; i++){
        if(list[i] == arguments->target){
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    theStatus = &result;
    free(args);
    pthread_exit((void*)theStatus);
    return (void*)theStatus;
}
```

Now my question is, what is the most efficient way to free my struct after it completes the function splitSearch? Would free(args) or free(arguments) suffice? Would it interfere with other threads running the same code because the initial pthread_create() call is ran in a loop afterall. Lastly, I thought of creating an array in which each index will hold a malloced struct but then I would need to traverse this array and free each struct individually which is why I was hoping to free it as soon as it fulfills its purpose.

Comment: Either works. You can `free` on the thread, even if you `malloc`ed on `main`. So long as they match 1v1 you should be fine. Frankly, I am more concerned about sending the address of an automatic variable `result` out through *either* `pthread_exit` or that return value. Either of those is a recipe for disaster for anyone `pthread_join`-ing that thing and expecting a resolvable entity when done. And finally, unrelated, this is C. This code cleans up considerably if you stop with all the superfluous, unnecessary casting (which is *all* of them).

Comment: Sounds good, so just to clarify you’re suggesting removing the casting when I malloc, send args through pthread_create, and when returning theStatus to pthread_join? I’m asking because I was following syntax I’ve seen online as pthread_create and pthread_join both have void* parameters.

Comment: Honestly ? I'd put the result status inside your Arguments structure, *not* free the structure in the thread, and and rather just free it after reaping it back from `pthread_join` and fetching your status. That is, assuming you're needing that status in the first place. If you don't actually *need* it, then just do what I described earlier. There are other options, but those are probably the easiest to adapt to your code.

Comment: So it's exactly as you said it. I was not able to retrieve the value correctly when `pthread_join` -ing. I tried putting the return value within a field of the Arguments struct and sending the struct back via `pthread_exit` but it still retrieves the value incorrectly. I know there are other ways of retrieving the value back in the main but I was assigned to use `pthread_exit` to retrieve thread return values.

Comment: Your post should reflect the changes you made via addendum. I'm particularly interested in how you're joining the thread to retrieve the result out of your arguments struct. Also, this may seem superlative, but remember, if you stuff the result back in your `Arguments` struct, you don't free it on the thread; it gets freed back wherever he `pthread_join` reaps the pointer result, gets the data out of the structure, and when finished, *then* free the arguments.